# Haskell parse error in function definition

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to compile this function:

```
fff [] _ = []
fff (x:xs) ys
   | r == [] = xs1
   | otherwise ys ++ xs1
   where r = filter (x<) ys 
         xs1 = fff xs ys
```

But I get this error:

> Test.hs:14:4: parse error on input `where'
>
> Failed, modules loaded: none.

Any help to solve it?

Thanks,
Sebastián.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the required `=` after `otherwise`.

By the way, `r == []` better be replaced by the more general `null r`.

Try this:

```
fff [] _ = []
fff (x:xs) ys
    | r == [] = xs1
    | otherwise = ys ++ xs1
    where r = filter (x<) ys 
          xs1 = fff xs ys
```

Comment: The better reason to use `null` over `== []` is because `== []` requires that your list be of type `Eq a => [a]`, where `null :: [a] -> Bool`, so `null` works on _all_ lists, not just lists of `Eq a => a` values.